# Where did Django form wizard go in django 1.8?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

There is a [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) about form wizard for version 1.7 but not for 1.8. I have looked at [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/) and there is no mention of this. So where did it go? (Also there seems to be no class named SessionWizardView [anywhere](https://github.com/django/django/search?q=SessionWizardView&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) in 1.8).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The wizard is part of the formtools package which has been split off into a separate repository.

New project:
https://github.com/django/django-formtools/

More info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#removal-of-django-contrib-formtools